# Adding a set to a database table, using format string - how to include null values

Tags: python, mysql, sql, flask, set

I have a set that depending on the situation can contain anywhere between 1 and 5 elements. I am saving this set to a database table using a format string. My table contains 5 tables, but when creating it, I did include that it was okay to have null values in the columns.

my set below can be:

```
small = set(1, 2, 3,4,5)
```

but it can also be:

```
small = set(1,2,3)
```

This is my insert statement within my database table.

```
cursor = mysql.connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
query2 = "INSERT INTO StreamingService (movie_id, service1, service2, service3, service4, service5) VALUES ((select id from movies), % s, % s, % s, % s, % s)"
cursor.execute(query2, small)
mysql.connection.commit()
```

I know that I need to find a way to make my table accept the set, even without 5 values in the set and include null values in the empty spaces.

Any help, advice would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need convert your `set` into a `list` and then add  `None` to the list for each missing value.  You could append `None` for each missing value or create a list of `None` and extend your "small" list.

```
small = set(1,2,3)

fixed = list(small)
# Make a list of None, one per missing value
extras = [None] * (5 - len(small))
# Add the None list to the list of values to make up the count.
fixed.extend(extras) 

cursor = mysql.connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
query2 = "INSERT INTO StreamingService (movie_id, service1, service2, service3, service4, service5) VALUES ((select id from movies), %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
cursor.execute(query2, fixed)
mysql.connection.commit()
```

Comment: Ahh this is perfect I see what this has done it has made it into [1,2,3, None, None]. Thank you. I tried to use this however it works but inserting it into the database is stil a problem it returns MySQLdb.OperationalError: (1242, 'Subquery returns more than 1 row').

Comment: Can None be accepted by mysql database as Null Values ?

Comment: Usually driver package (mysql.connector, pymysql etc) will convert `None` to `NULL` when injecting the values into the SQL statement.

Comment: Your subquery is returning every id in the movies table - you need to find way to limit it to the id you want by specifying some unique value in the movies table.  For example, if each movie's name is unique the subquery would be `SELECT id FROM movies WHERE name = %s` (you would have to insert the name into the values passed to the query).

Comment: yes i get it now. No wonder, i was always having these issues. Is it possible to have something like cursor.execute(query2, fixed, data). Data being the specific id that I want. And then when I want SELECT id FROM movies WHERE name = %s, it goes as a value there?, Or is it that I actually just that I put the variable data into the first position of the list fixed.

Comment: It should be first in the `fixed` list `fixed.insert(0, 'something')`

Answer (score 0):

update your table to accept nulls, and while inserting the data in your code initialize the variables as null before getting the values from the user.

Comment: My table columns do accept null values, but what do you mean by initialize the variables, as null? The elements in my set are from an API, which i have put into a set.

Comment: Which language are you using ?